# Is there a risk of a DIY pre amp damaging a microphone?

Tags: amplifier, analog, audio, microphone, preamp

I'm looking for a preamplifier to use with an aquarian A1S hydrophone. This is an application where signal integrity is not very important and we're going to filter and do a fourier transform on the signal. It seems like the pre amps that Aquarian sells are probably overkill for our applications. If it doesn't work we can always just bite the bullet and get a higher quality pre amp. I'm wondering if there's any kind of risk of damaging the mic using a DIY eBay preamplifier for this hydrophone. I attached links to the hydrophone and the DIY preamplifier below.

https://www.aquarianaudio.com/as-1-hydrophone.html

https://www.ebay.ca/itm/173519955766

Comment: there is always a risk ... if you want to know any more details, then post the schematic diagram of the preamp

Comment: The amplifier is made for dynamic mics. It also has no specs about input impedance or gain or bandwidth, so even if it does not damage the hydrophone, it may be completely unusable with a piezo hydrophone requiring a high impedance input. It makes no sense to try using a random $4 hobby amplifier board with a sensitive $400 precision instrument. Even a generic hi-z USB audio interface would be better solution.

Answer (score 3):

The risk should be very low.

That is a stereo (2 channel) preamp of unknown fixed gain.  It has coupling capacitors in and out, so the frequency response probably will not be flat down to 1 Hz, the spec for the hydrophone.  Depending on the gain, it also probably will not be flat to 100 kHz either.  A typical gain for this type of module is 40 dB (100x).

One solution is to replace the input and output coupling capacitors with ones larger by 10x or more.  A better way is to create an all DC-coupled amp circuit with a DC servo to keep the output centered about a fixed operating point.  You cannot do that with the module you linked because it is not running on dual +/- power supplies.

The 5532 is an excellent low noise part, the first "audio opamp".  If I were starting from scratch, I would have the two opamp sections in series, each one with a gain of 10.  This would get you much better bandwidth at the cost of a small noise increase.  National and Burr-Brown have newer opamps with better performance.

Please update your question:  What is the signal voltage range out of the hydrophone?  What bandwidth do you need in the preamp?  What gain do you need?

Comment: (Probably) not a damage risk factor, but the eBay NE5532 may be real, or it might be something else from the Huaqiangbei market.